# Subcaption, and the ever-changing width of a subtable

Tags: subcaption

I'm using `subcaption` to layout two tables of different widths side by side, but I do not understand how I am supposed to know the width of the tables beforehand. What am I supposed to write in place of those `*`s?

```
\begin{table}[p]
    \centering
    \begin{subtable}{*}
        \begin{tabular}{rccc}
        \toprule
        & {\bf\small no}
        & {\bf\small informally}
        & {\bf\small formally} \\ \midrule
        {\bf\small beginners}       & {\bf 4} & 3 & 1 \\
        {\bf\small non-beginners}   & 0       & 0 & {\bf 12} \\
        {\bf\small total}           & 4       & 3 & {\bf 13} \\ \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{Q1: Have you studied music?}
    \end{subtable}
    \qquad
    \begin{subtable}{*}
        \begin{tabular}{ccc}
        \toprule
        {\bf\small no}
        & {\bf\small one}
        & {\bf\small more} \\ \midrule
        {\bf 6} &      2  & 0 \\
             1  & {\bf 6} & 5 \\
        {\bf 7} & {\bf 8} & 5 \\ \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{Q2: Do you play a musical instrument?}
    \end{subtable}
\end{table}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `\subcaptionbox` instead which will have a width equal to the width of the content (unless modified through an optional argument):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[p]
    \centering
    \subcaptionbox{Q1: Have you studied music?}{%
        \begin{tabular}{>{\bfseries\small}rccc}
        \toprule
        & \bfseries\small no
        & \bfseries\small informally
        & \bfseries\small formally \\ \midrule
        beginners       & \bfseries 4 & 3 & 1 \\
        non-beginners   & 0       & 0 & \bfseries 12 \\
        total           & 4       & 3 & \bfseries 13 \\ \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}}\qquad
    \subcaptionbox{Q2: Do you play a musical instrument?}{%
        \begin{tabular}{>{\bfseries\small}ccc}
        \toprule
        no
        & \bfseries\small one
        & \bfseries\small more \\ \midrule
        6 &      2  & 0 \\
             1  & \bfseries 6 & 5 \\
        7 & \bfseries 8 & 5 \\ \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

## Remarks

- `\bf` is obsolete, use `\bfseries` instead.
- Since each cell forms a group, there's no need for explicit grouping.
- Using the `>{...}` syntax from the `array` package you can use `>{\bfseries\small}` to apply those settings for a whole column.